# I'm able to edit my deleted question, but I cannot look at it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

I'm able to edit my [deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/) but I cannot look at it nor undelete it. After pressing the *Save my Edits* button I'm redirected to a 404 page, but by reloading the edit page I'm able to see my the new revision.

Here's [the edit link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/34151/edit/), that I can use to edit it. How did I get that edit link? Simple: I deleted the question and pressed the edit link thinking that I could undelete it later. (Which I can't… well, maybe I could using the correct link.)

Comment: Delicious waffles ...

Comment: A better link is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/

Comment: I actually had it like this some time…

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the delete-edit-undelete technique only works for answers (unless you have a reputation >= 10K or are a moderator). At one time, you could close your question while you edited it and then re-open it when you were done... but that's no longer possible either.

There are other restrictions on deleting questions that make this an inflexible practice, even if you do have the rep to pull it off in some instances. It's probably best to just consider a deleted question *gone* and post your edits as a new question (which I see you've done).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Paste following on URL bar on **current** post (apparently any different post) to **undelete** that post.

```
javascript:$.post("/posts/34151/vote/11",{fkey:fkey})
```

I've tested on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/49318/revisions) question, only 10k+ users can see