# Privileges aren't enforced correctly when editing deleted posts

Tags: bug, privileges, security

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Deleted posts can still be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89777/deleted-posts-can-still-be-edited)
>   [I'm able to edit my deleted question, but I cannot look at it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/im-able-to-edit-my-deleted-question-but-i-cannot-look-at-it)

Permissions aren't enforced correctly in the post editor, allowing under-10k users to view deleted posts whose IDs they know.

- [Here is a deleted question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99366/clarify-wording-on-badge-page-for-post-associated-badges-that-you-can-only-earn-o). This is only visible to 10k+ users.
- [Here is the page to edit it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99366/edit) This *should* only be visible to 10k+ users, but is visible to everyone.

As much as it will disappoint me to lose this newfound ability, this should probably be fixed.

---

#### Re: [Deleted posts can still be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89777/deleted-posts-can-still-be-edited)

If this is the intended behaviour, then there is a related bug: I can't see my own deleted question. There's no way for me to vote to reopen it, as Jeff says in that post.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't actually a duplicate, I confused my comment on Jeff's answer with the actual question. [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34175) is actually more related to your specific scenario.

Comment: I can't confirm this for other deleted questions. For example, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/edit is not visible to non-10k+ users.

Comment: I have posted [a new question asking about the intended behaviour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave).